# Use of if statement for list in python?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a list of words like the following:

```
old_list = ['houses','babies','cars','apples']
```

The output I need is:

```
new_list = ['house','baby','car','apple']
```

In order to do this, I came up with a loop:

```
new_list1 = []
new_list2 = []
for word in old_list:
    if word.endswith("ies"):
        new_list1[:0] = [word.replace("ies","y")] 
    elif word.endswith("s"):
        new_list2[:0] = [word.replace(' ','')[:-1]]

new_list = new_list1 + new_list2 # Order doesn't matter, but len(new_list) == len(old_list)
```

It's simply not working. I'm getting something like:

```
new_list = ['baby','house','babie','car','apple']
```

I'm sure I'm just doing one simple thing wrong but I can't see it. And I would use list.append() if there's an easy way to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting ``['baby', 'apple', 'car', 'house']`` with your code.

Comment: even i am getting same answer as @Bogdan ...and remove that space between new_list and 2!!

Comment: I'm checking my code again, I didn't realize that the mistake may be coming from something else. Sorry.

Comment: @Bogdan: I have a question though, how would you remove any words containing anything else than letters and dashes?

Comment: @marc, remove from where? I guess something along the lines of ``[s for s in l if re.match(r'[\-\w]*$', s)]`` (or with an analogous ``filter``).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `word.replace("ies","y")` is not a very good idea; sometimes you can find it in the middle of the word e.g. `diesel`

```
new_list = []
for word in old_list:
    if word.endswith("s"):
        if word.endswith("ies"):
            new_list.append(word[:-3] + "y")
        else:
            new_list.append(word[:-1])
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. The issue is that I needed to check for s first.

Comment: How would you then replace all words containing "degree" (ie. "50-degrees" with the word "degree"? I tried new_list.append("degree"), but it still returns the whole word.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understand. If the old_list contains `50-degrees`, the new one will contain `50-degree`. If you need to remove `50-`, then you need to formalize the rule, e.g. remove evertyhing before `-`.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't directly address your question (why your attempted code doesn't work as expected) but I suggest to not use a loop in the first place - instead, have a dedicated function for giving the singular form of a given english word, like:

```
def singular(word):
  # ...
  return singularForm
```

And then use a list comprehension

```
new_list = [singular(word) for word in old_list]
```

It's shorter and IMHO nicely communicates what you do: getting the singular form of every word in `old_list` instead of talking about *how* it's done (by looping over the list).

Answer (score 4):

> And I would use list.append() if there's an easy way to implement it.

I think you're misunderstanding how `list.append()` works. Remember that lists are mutable, so you don't need to do the `new_list1[:0] = blah`. You can just do:

```
new_list = []
for word in old_list:
    if word.endswith("ies"):
        new_list.append(word.replace("ies","y"))
    elif word.endswith("s"):
        new_list.append(word.replace(' ',''))
```

Also I'm not seeing what your second replace function should be. If you want to get rid of the `'s'` (for words such as `'houses'`), you can use slicing:

```
>>> print 'houses'[:-1]
house
```

Comment: slicing won't turn `babies` into `baby`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I showed the slicing for the second replace. It's not intended for the `-ies` words

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought "second replace" would be the one you're *not* addressing with your slicing remark.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I clarified it a bit :)

Comment: I believe he wanted to remove trailing spaces at the end of word and then to get rid of the `s`. Something like `print 'houses  '[:-1]` -> `house`. If I'm right, it may me better written using `strip`: `word.strip()[:-1]`

Comment: Thanks, but just to clarify. With the elif statement, the word will only go through one or the other. Correct?

Comment: @user2454855 Yes, it will go through one or the other

Answer (score 0):

```
#Use list comprehension to less code#
old_list = ['houses','babies','cars','apples']
new_list = ['house','baby','car','apple']
new_list+=[word.replace('ies','y') for word in old_list if word.endswith('ies')]
```

Comment: -1 Just dumping a snippet of code without any further explanation is not very educational.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in one line.

```
new_list = [word[:-1].replace('ie','y') for word in old_list]
```

Just be careful of words like 'pies' because the code will turn it into 'py'. Maybe that is Python trying to send us secret messages. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
old_list = ['cars', 'babies', 'computers', 'words']

def remove_s_ies(string):
    if string.endswith('ies'):
        return string[:-3]+'y'
    elif string.endswith('s'):
        return string[:-1]


new_words = [ remove_s_ies(word) for word in old_list ]
```